# Getting the case class instead of the trait in dynRenderR

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am working on a scalajs-react project, and I can't get the following to type check. The relevant documentation is [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/ROUTER.md#dynamic-routes) and [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/doc/ROUTER.md#actions).

---

My pages are:

```
sealed trait Pages
case class Product(id: String) extends Pages
```

My routes are defined as:

```
dynamicRouteCT("#product" / string("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
   .caseClass[Product]) ~> dynRenderR((page, ctl) => ProductPage(page, ctl))
```

The problem is that the dynRenderR component is returning a value of type `Pages`, when I really need a value of type `Product` in order to access the id property, which the `Pages` trait does not have.

The product page:

```
case class Props(routeData: Product, ctl: RouterCtl[Pages])

class Backend($: BackendScope[Props, Unit]) {
    def render(props: Props) = <.div("Product view " + props.routeData.id)
}

def apply(product: Product, ctl: RouterCtl[Pages]): ReactElement =
    component(Props(product, ctl))

private val component = ReactComponentB[Props]("Product")
    .renderBackend[Backend]
    .build
```

Strangely, this compiles and runs no problem; it is intellij which is complaining with:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Product, actual Pages
```

How can I modify or correctly utilize the dynRender component to pass a Product instead of a Pages, or can it not be used this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Strangely, this compiles and runs no problem; it is intellij which is complaining [...]

Unfortunatley, Intellij's compilation/error reporting is not perfect, especially in presence of macros. While I don't know the details of scalajs-react, you can rest assured that if your code compiles and runs fine, you just see an Intellij bug.

So all you can do is:

- Live with it or
- file a bug.

Sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: It seems like a valid type error though. If a Product was passed where a Pages was expected, that would be fine, in the reverse case, a Pages cannot do everything a Product can, so it is a type error. So I don't understand why this is compiling.

Comment: Inside the call to `dynamicRouteCT` you are explicitly stating that your parameters should be parsed as `Product` by saying: `.caseClass[Product]`. This propagates through to the call to `dynRenderR`.